# Issue in DateTime Picker MVC2

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, datepicker

I had done a application with DateTime Picker. Current Date is displaying in the control. But the calender is not working.Whenever i click the TextBox nothing happens..

Here is my Code in Site.Master

```
 <title>
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="TitleContent" runat="server" />
</title>
<link href="../../Content/Site.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="../../Content/jquery-ui-1.8.1.custom.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="../../Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../../Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.1.custom.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#UseDatePicker").live('click', function () {
            $(this).datepicker('destroy').datepicker({
                showOn: 'focus',
                changeMonth: true,
                changeYear: true
            }).focus();
        });
    });
</script>
```

In my index.aspx...

```
<p><%:Html.LabelFor(m => m.MyDate)%>:&nbsp;<%:Html.EditorFor(m => m.MyDate) %></p>
```

In my Model.cs

```
 [DisplayName("Date")]
    public DateTime MyDate { get; set; }
```

In my DateTime.ascx

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<System.DateTime?>" %>
<%=Html.TextBox("", (Model.HasValue ? Model.Value.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy") : DateTime.Today.ToShortDateString()), new { @class = "UseDatePicker date-text-box" })%>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your javascript in the Site.Master, you have what looks like an incorrect selector - you have `#UseDatePicker` - which is an **ID** selector, but in your editor template, you assign the **class** `UseDatePicker`.

You probably want to change the selector in the site master to `.UseDatePicker`.

And I have no idea why you're doing the whole destroy thing - I don't know what you're trying to achieve there...

Answer (score 0):

Actually it should be:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.UseDatePicker').datepicker({
        showOn: 'focus',
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true
    });
});
```

Comment: I am getting the value of alert..But not the calender........<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            alert('a');
            $('.UseDatePicker').datepicker({
                showOn: 'focus',
                changeMonth: true,
                changeYear: true
            });
        });
    </script>

Comment: No idea what's wrong with your code but here's a demo illustrating a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/mr92f/. Make sure you've properly included all scripts and that the css class name is correct.

Comment: In the above source code,where we are mentioning the click of the textbox, so that the calender will be displayed

Comment: I had added a ViewUserControl1.ascx file(Which is DateTime.ascx) and had given this code "<%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<System.DateTime?>" %>
<%=Html.TextBox("", (Model.HasValue ? Model.Value.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy") : DateTime.Today.ToShortDateString()), new { @class = "UseDatePicker date-text-box" })%>" ....Whether i should change anything in this...

Answer (score 0):

I am getting the value of alert..But not the calender.

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        alert('a');
        $('.UseDatePicker').datepicker({
            showOn: 'focus',
            changeMonth: true,
            changeYear: true
        });
    });
</script>
```